# Detecting touchpad movement vs regular mouse programmatically on Linux

Tags: linux, awesome-wm, touchpad

I love the mod4 + mouse-drag combo for moving/resizing windows in Awesome WM, it's very intuitive with regular mouse. Now that I'm using Awesome WM on my laptop, however, I find this combo more annoying when using the touchpad vs regular mouse.

The problem stems from the fact that I now need 3 fingers to perform a gesture that I could do with 2 before (1 to move on the touchpad, 1 to keep on the left-click at all times, and one on mod4). Alternatively, I can apply more force to the touchpad and have it pressed as I drag my finger, which is not any better since it puts a lot of stress on the finger doing the dragging).

What I would like to do instead is have awesome treat left-mouse button as pressed if both of the following conditions are met:

- mod4 is pressed
- movement event is coming from touchpad and not regular mouse

To do so, however, I need to be able to detect that the movement is coming from the touchpad. Is there a way to do so in Awesome WM/Linux? I've looked through the keysyms (http://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/List_of_keysyms) but don't see anything for the mouse. I've also looked at the mouse.lua file in Awesome WM but it doesn't seem to have anything to differentiate between the two either (https://github.com/awesomeWM/awesome/blob/master/lib/awful/mouse/init.lua). If there is a way to tell that the last coordinate change came from a touchpad on Linux that would resolve the issue as I could simply create a lua file to run such check whenever Mod4 is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

> To do so, however, I need to be able to detect that the movement is coming from the touchpad. Is there a way to do so in Awesome WM/Linux?

Nope, there is no such way in AwesomeWM. Sorry.

In X11, this is possible via the input extension. However, awesome does not use that extension.